# SQL ORDER BY DESC not working with multiple ordering options?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I need to select text from two columns but also order by pubdate desc.

"title LIKE ? AND description LIKE ?" works in two columns, and I get the result I expected, but "pubdate" is not ordering DESC.

I need to use title LIKE ? AND description LIKE ? + pubdate DESC

pubdate is a timestamp number.

**pubdate ordering now:**
old,
new,
old,
new,
old

**how i need to order:**
new,
new,
old,
old,
old

I tried this SQL query but it failed.

```
SELECT source,title,description,link,pubdate
FROM feeds
USE INDEX(PRIMARY,idx_title_description)
WHERE MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY title LIKE ? AND description LIKE ? AND pubdate DESC
LIMIT 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `ORDER BY` clauses are structured like `SELECT` clauses, not like `WHERE` clauses. They have a comma-separated list of columns.
2. Expressions such as `title LIKE ?` yield the value `1` when true and `0` when false.

So, if you want to order your resultset by most recent date, but showing the matching ones first, you need.

```sql
ORDER BY (title LIKE ? AND description LIKE ?) DESC, pubdate DESC
```

The first DESC is there because you want the rows where `(title LIKE ? AND description LIKE ?)` is true -- has the value `1` -- first, then the ones where it's false -- `0` -- second.

This `true` / `false` :: `1` / `0` thing is a MySQL-specific hack.  To be portable to other DBMS makes, you want

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE ? AND description LIKE ? THEN 1
              ELSE 0 END  DESC, 
         pubdate DESC
```

This puts all the matching rows first in your result set, then the non-matching ones.  If you want them ordered by date, and the matching ones to show up first within each date, flip the order of the two items in the `ORDER BY`:

```sql
ORDER BY pubdate DESC, (title LIKE ? AND description LIKE ?) DESC
```